# How to make two divs share the remaining width?

Tags: css, html

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="b">
        Text
    </div>
    <div class="c" style="width:100px">
        Text
    </div>  
</div>
```

How can I make each of the b divs take up 50% of the remaining width in a?
I want something looking like this:

```
+----------------+----------------+-------+
|50% of remaining|50% of remaining| 100px |
+----------------+----------------+-------+
```

You can put a div around the b divs if that makes it easier.

Is this possible without javascript? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using [calc()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
div>div {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.a{
    width:100%;
}

.b{
    width: calc(50% - (100px / 2)); /* 100px / 2 div.b */ 
    background:red;
}

.c{
    width:100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WM6H8/1/)

[CanIUse calc()](http://caniuse.com/calc)

Comment: I like it :) Totally forgot about `calc` ;)

Comment: @mdesdev yes, I love `calc()` but its a shame that it doesn't have better browser support

Comment: Yeah, shame, very nice function.

Comment: Thats a brilliant use. This is a good demo example of how calc is very useful

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display:table` for just this purpose:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/UcX2Z/)

HTML

```
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Text</div>
    <div class="b">Text</div>
    <div class="c">Text</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.a{
    display:table;
}
.b, .c{
    display:table-cell;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.b{
    width:50%;
}
.c{
    width:100px;
}
```

Note you need to also close your `.a` div, and as noted below, remove `style="100px"` which isnt valid.

Comment: Just a note, `style="100px"` isn't valid.

Comment: You need to remove the margins for the elements `.b`: `2*50% + margins` will be higher than `100%`.

Comment: @Vucko - you're right, I'd had quickly copied over the original HTML

Comment: @RoyiNamir - I dont think so, the width of `.a` is unspecified, `.c` must be `100px` and both `.b` must be 50% of the remainder.

Comment: if c is 100px , so what is the remainder to `.b` ? (table-(c+a)) ?

Comment: Whoops, I ment to write style="width:100px"

Answer (score 0):

Here's a <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/3GjSN/)**</kbd>

```
.a {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.b,
.c {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
.b {
  width: 44.5%;
}
.c {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.b { width: calc(50% - 50px); }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nLFkA/)